# Show a div tag only if a person is logged in

Tags: asp.net

I was trying to incorporate a functionality in my ASP.NET such that  a `DIV` tag which contains the `Profile Navigation Menu`  should only be visible if a person is logged in. 
I know the condition on how to if the person is logged in or not but wanted to know the method to toggle the div tag on/off based on person's logged in status.

```
if(loggedin==yes)
{
//?
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just make sure you're not inadvertently depending on this for access control!  A non-logged in user fishing around in the HTML source shouldn't be able to get access to anything.

Comment: @payne: I hope this won't be a problem because the the profile page again has a check to see if the user is logged in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the div to `runat="server"`, and then access it as a variable in your code-behind page and set Visible to false.

That is, you'd have something like:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">
```

And then in your CS file:

```
if (!loggedIn)
{
    myDiv.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you div is having `runat=server` attribute. You can take the instance of it as follows:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

HtmlGenericControl div=Page.FindControl("myDiv");
div.Visible=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make it a server tag by adding the runat="server" then you can use divid.[Visable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.control.visible%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)=false to not display it